# Accommodating multiple states through $stateprovider in one $resource in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, resources, angular-resource

I have a requirement where the angularjs states for one particular page would be different. Say, /items/create and /items/list -- those 2 are my urls for 2 different states. Now, how do I accommodate them in one $resource? Is it possible? Or do I have to create 2 $resource or 2 factories?

```
<angular module>.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
    .state('items', {
        url: '/items/create',
        templateUrl: '<view>'
    })
    .state('items.List', {
        url: '/items/list',
        templateUrl: '<view>'
    });
}]);

<angular module>.factory('Items', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('/items');
}]);
```

Now this will not work, as the state urls are different. If i make the resource with /items/create, the first url will be executed and if make the resource with /items/list the second will be executed.

I need to make a resource which will refer to both of the states provided in the state provider. Is it possible?

Please note, I want to have them called at the page load itself before making any manual state transfer.

Comment: i didn't understand...can you elaborate more?? Thanks!!!!!

Comment: I have updated the main question content. Please have a look at it again and see if you have any solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly but you could make the resource url /items/:state and then pass in a state property when you call Items.query/get/post

Items.post({state:"create"});

Items.get({state:"list"});